# If else statement is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In this function the user selects a value in the dropdown menu and whatever value is selected, it would change var `B` to its corresponding value.

```
function test(){
    var A = ["", "A", "B", "C"];
    var B = document.getElementById("myfile");

    if(A.value = "A"){
        B.selectedIndex = [2];
    }
    else if(A.value = "B"){
        B.selectedIndex = [4];
    }
    else if(A.value = "C"){
        B.selectedIndex = [1];
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that every time I select B or C, it always defaults to index [2] and not [4] or [1].

Comment: You compare things with `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 5):

You're assigning when you mean to compare. Use `==`, not `=`, for comparison.

```
if(A.value == "A"){
    B.selectedIndex = [2];
}
else if(A.value == "B"){
    B.selectedIndex = [4];
}
else if(A.value == "C"){
    B.selectedIndex = [1];
}
```

Comment: I tried using "==" and "===" but now it doesn't change B at all

Comment: As written, `A.value` doesn't exist. `A` is just an array. *Setting* the `value` property would succeed, and set index `2` every time. Without seeing where the real `A.value` is coming from (assuming it's not what we see in your sample code), it's hard to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment

`==` is test for equality for content

`===` is test for equality for content and data type

In your case, `=` is certainly a typo. I'd recommend using `===` for maximum program stability.

Some folk tend to write `"A" == A.value` so a misplaced assignment gives you a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the value in your ifs not testing it. This will return the value that is assigned. The if **condition will be true** unless the following values are assigned and therefore returned, **false**, **0**, an **empty string**, **null**, **undefined** or **NaN**. That's why you are entering the block of the first if statement.

Change the single equals to **double or triple equals**.

```
if(A.value == "A"){
    B.selectedIndex = [2];
}
else if(A.value == "B"){
    B.selectedIndex = [4];
}
else if(A.value == "C"){
    B.selectedIndex = [1];
}
```

Comment: Actually, the assignment operator returns you the value that it assigned.  It doesn't return a boolean; there's no way for an assignment to fail.  Try `if(foo = 0){}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use == not =

Your statement checks if its possible to set the value.(Every time...)

Comment: Actually, the assignment operator returns you the value that it assigned.